# Convert data rows to numeric matrix

Tags: r, matrix

I have an R question: efficiently building a matrix from rows.
data rows as a data frame:

```
name, date, value 
('a', '2014-01-02', 100)
('b', '2013-12-22', 200)
('a', '2014-02-12', 300)
('c', '2014-01-05', 400)
```

I'd like to build a matrix , in this case, it's 3 x 4, 3 names, and 4 dates, with the correct values padded into this matrix.

in the matrix,

```
row labels: a,b,c
column labels: '2013-12-22',  '2014-01-02', '2014-01-05',  '2014-02-12'
```

example value:

```
mat[ 1, 2  ]  = 100
mat[1,4] = 0
```

should i use hashtable ? or you have a better way to efficiently do it?

Comment: You are looking into [casting your molten data](https://www.google.com/search?q=r+cast+molten+data).

Comment: Namely, look for reshape2::dcast with fill=0